# Formatting the output in an object using apache poi

Tags: java, json, excel, object, apache-poi

[Excel File for reference](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bp06vg7BHSYZ5i858d63lFG7_F6765-X)Hello ppl I used the following code to read the excel sheet. can you help me formatting the output data in an object in such a way that I should get the below mentioned json structure when I convert the object to json using some api's? I have also attached the excel sheet img for ref. i.e output structure should be similar to Map(List(Map(Map))) and also please refer the json

[image: this is the excel img]

```
public class readingexcel {

    public void readXLSXFile(String fileName) {
        InputStream XlsxFileToRead = null;
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        try {
            XlsxFileToRead = new FileInputStream(fileName);

            //Getting the workbook instance for xlsx file
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(XlsxFileToRead);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //getting the first sheet from the workbook using sheet name. 
        // We can also pass the index of the sheet which starts from '0'.
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;

        //Iterating all the rows in the sheet
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();

            //Iterating all the cells of the current row
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();

                if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " ");
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " ");
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + " ");

                } else { // //Here if require, we can also add below methods to
                            // read the cell content
                            // XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK
                            // XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA
                            // XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            try {
                XlsxFileToRead.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readingexcel readXlsx = new readingexcel();
        readXlsx.readXLSXFile("stack.xlsx");    
    }

}
```

This is the json struture (please ignore the syntax)

```
Sheet1
    {
    Month
            [
                {
                    BL :
                        {
                            "A":42,
                            "B":19,
                            "C":20,
                            "D":11,
                            "E":22,
                            "F":44,
                            "G":76,
                            "H":12                  
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        JAN :
                        {
                            "A":6,
                            "B":4,
                            "C":2,
                            "D":1,
                            "E":8,
                            "F":7,
                            "G":2,
                            "H":5                   
                        }
                    }
                    FEB :
                        {
                            "A":5,
                            "B":6,
                            "C":8,
                            "D":9,
                            "E":7,
                            "F":6,
                            "G":4,
                            "H":2                   
                        }
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        DEC :
                        {
                            "A":4,
                            "B":2,
                            "C":1,
                            "D":9,
                            "E":8,
                            "F":7,
                            "G":4,
                            "H":3                   
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        WEEK
        [
            {
                BL:
                {
                    "I":42,
                    "J":19,
                    "K":20
                }
                WK-01:
                {
                    "I":6,
                    "J":4
                    "K":2
                }
                WK-02:
                {
                    "I":5,
                    "J":6,
                    "K":8
                }
                .
                .
                .
                WK-52:
                {
                    "I":1,
                    "J":4,
                    "K":6
                }

            }
        ]
```

Comment: you can refer to this article https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-java

Comment: Please provide a link to download the xls file, can't work with an image.

Comment: How do you plan on exporting the JSON?

Comment: @Bentaye please check I have attached the excel file thanks in advance

Comment: @GalAbracan Not planned yet I have heard that there are few api's that convert the array into json ,if you have  any idea please suggest .

Comment: @rahuluday cheers, will have a look. Is it ok to use external libraries?

Comment: @Bentaye yeah sure want the output in this structure Map(List(Map(Map))) and also refer json structure provided. Thank you

Comment: `Map(List(Map(Map)))` does not mean anything, the JSON you show represents `Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>>`

Comment: @rahuluday I posted an answer, should do what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete code to parse the file into a `Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>>>` as required (See suggested improvements at the end)

- This can parse all the sheets you have in your XLS file, as long as they all have the same general table structure.
- The table positions are automatically found (because their name is on the top left corner), you just have to provide the name of the table to the `extractTable()` method.

**Code**

```
public class ExcelReader {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonString = new ExcelReader().fileToJson("stack.xlsx");
    System.out.print(jsonString);
  }

  // Parses the file into a JSON string
  private String fileToJson(String filename) {
    List<XSSFSheet> sheets = getSheets(filename);
    Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>>> workbookMap = parseSheets(sheets);
    return toJsonString(workbookMap);
  }

  // Make a list of XSSFSheets out of the file
  private List<XSSFSheet> getSheets(String fileName) {
    List<XSSFSheet> sheets = new ArrayList<>();
    try(InputStream XlsxFileToRead = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
      //Getting the workbook instance for xlsx file
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(XlsxFileToRead);

      //Getting all the sheets
      for (int i=0; i<workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
        sheets.add(workbook.getSheetAt(i));
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sheets;
  }

  // Parse a list of sheets into the desired structure
  private Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>>> parseSheets(List<XSSFSheet> xsshSheets) {
    Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>>> workbookMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(XSSFSheet xssfSheet : xsshSheets) {
      String name = xssfSheet.getSheetName();
      Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>> sheetMap = parseSheet(xssfSheet);
      workbookMap.put(name, sheetMap);
    }
    return workbookMap;
  }


  // Parses a sheet into the desired structure
  private Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>> parseSheet(XSSFSheet xsshSheet) {
    List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> months = extractTable(xsshSheet, "Month");
    List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> weeks = extractTable(xsshSheet, "Week");
    List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> days = extractTable(xsshSheet, "Daily");

    Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>> sheet = new HashMap<>();
    sheet.put("MONTH", months);
    sheet.put("WEEK", weeks);
    sheet.put("DAILY", days);
    return sheet;
  }

  // Extracts a table
  private List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> extractTable(XSSFSheet sheet, String tableName) {
    Cell tablePosition = findTablePosition(sheet, tableName);
    if(tablePosition!=null)
      return extractTable(sheet, tablePosition);
    else return null;
  }

  // Finds the position of the cell with the given text
  private Cell findTablePosition(XSSFSheet sheet, String tableName) {
    for (Row row : sheet) {
      for (Cell cell : row) {
        if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING && tableName.equals(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
          return cell;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  // Extract a table
  private List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> extractTable(XSSFSheet sheet, Cell tablePosition) {
    List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> table = new ArrayList<>();

    int headerRow = tablePosition.getRowIndex();
    int valuesHeaderColumn = tablePosition.getColumnIndex();

    // read all columns and rows until finding an empty one
    int row = headerRow + 1;
    int col = valuesHeaderColumn + 1;

    // read all columns starting at col
    while(true) {
      Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> tableColumn = new HashMap<>();
      Cell headerCell = sheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(col);
      if(headerCell == null)
        break;
      String columnName = headerCell.getStringCellValue().toUpperCase();
      if("".equals(columnName))
        break;

      // read all rows starting at row
      Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();
      while(true) {
        Row valueHeaderRow = sheet.getRow(row);
        if(valueHeaderRow == null)
          break;
        Cell valueHeaderCell = valueHeaderRow.getCell(valuesHeaderColumn);
        String valueHeader = valueHeaderCell.getStringCellValue();
        if("".equals(valueHeader))
          break;
        Cell valueCell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col);
        Integer value = (int)valueCell.getNumericCellValue();
        values.put(valueHeader, value);
        row++;
      }

      tableColumn.put(columnName, values);
      // Add the columns map to the list
      table.add(tableColumn);
      col++;
      row = headerRow + 1;
    }
    return table;
  }

  // Create the JSON string using Jackson ObjectMapper
  private String toJsonString(Object o) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = null;
    try {
      jsonString = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(o);
    } catch(JsonProcessingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonString;
  }
}
```

**Generated JSON** (using Jackson's `ObjectMapper`):

```
{
  "Sheet2" : {
    "MONTH" : [ {
      "BL" : {
        "A" : 42,
        "B" : 19,
        "C" : 20,
        "D" : 11,
        "E" : 22,
        "F" : 44,
        "G" : 76,
        "H" : 12
      }
    }, {
      "JAN" : {
        "A" : 4,
        "B" : 4,
        "C" : 2,
        "D" : 1,
        "E" : 8,
        "F" : 7,
        "G" : 2,
        "H" : 5
      }
    }, {
      "FEB" : {
        "A" : 5,
        "B" : 6,
        "C" : 8,
        "D" : 9,
        "E" : 7,
        "F" : 6,
        "G" : 4,
        "H" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "MAR" : {
        "A" : 4,
        "B" : 2,
        "C" : 1,
        "D" : 9,
        "E" : 8,
        "F" : 7,
        "G" : 4,
        "H" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "APR" : {
        "A" : 5,
        "B" : 6,
        "C" : 6,
        "D" : 4,
        "E" : 3,
        "F" : 2,
        "G" : 1,
        "H" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "MAY" : {
        "A" : 5,
        "B" : 3,
        "C" : 2,
        "D" : 1,
        "E" : 6,
        "F" : 7,
        "G" : 6,
        "H" : 5
      }
    }, {
      "JUN" : {
        "A" : 6,
        "B" : 7,
        "C" : 8,
        "D" : 6,
        "E" : 4,
        "F" : 3,
        "G" : 2,
        "H" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "JUL" : {
        "A" : 4,
        "B" : 6,
        "C" : 3,
        "D" : 4,
        "E" : 5,
        "F" : 7,
        "G" : 9,
        "H" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "AUG" : {
        "A" : 1,
        "B" : 5,
        "C" : 3,
        "D" : 6,
        "E" : 7,
        "F" : 8,
        "G" : 1,
        "H" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "SEP" : {
        "A" : 4,
        "B" : 5,
        "C" : 4,
        "D" : 3,
        "E" : 5,
        "F" : 2,
        "G" : 4,
        "H" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "OCT" : {
        "A" : 1,
        "B" : 2,
        "C" : 4,
        "D" : 5,
        "E" : 7,
        "F" : 9,
        "G" : 8,
        "H" : 7
      }
    }, {
      "NOV" : {
        "A" : 5,
        "B" : 6,
        "C" : 8,
        "D" : 9,
        "E" : 7,
        "F" : 6,
        "G" : 4,
        "H" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "DEC" : {
        "A" : 4,
        "B" : 2,
        "C" : 1,
        "D" : 9,
        "E" : 8,
        "F" : 7,
        "G" : 4,
        "H" : 3
      }
    } ],
    "DAILY" : [ {
      "BL" : {
        "L" : 42,
        "M" : 19,
        "N" : 20
      }
    }, {
      "D-01" : {
        "L" : 6,
        "M" : 4,
        "N" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "D-02" : {
        "L" : 5,
        "M" : 6,
        "N" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "D-03" : {
        "L" : 4,
        "M" : 2,
        "N" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "D-04" : {
        "L" : 5,
        "M" : 6,
        "N" : 6
      }
    }, {
      "D-05" : {
        "L" : 5,
        "M" : 3,
        "N" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "D-06" : {
        "L" : 6,
        "M" : 7,
        "N" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "D-07" : {
        "L" : 4,
        "M" : 6,
        "N" : 3
      }
    } ],
    "WEEK" : [ {
      "BL" : {
        "I" : 42,
        "J" : 19,
        "K" : 20
      }
    }, {
      "WK-01" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 4,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-02" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-03" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-04" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 6
      }
    }, {
      "WK-05" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 3,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-06" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 7,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-07" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-08" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-09" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-10" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-11" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-12" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-13" : {
        "I" : 42,
        "J" : 19,
        "K" : 20
      }
    }, {
      "WK-14" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 4,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-15" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-16" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-17" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 6
      }
    }, {
      "WK-18" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 3,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-19" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 7,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-20" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-21" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-22" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-23" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-24" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-25" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-26" : {
        "I" : 42,
        "J" : 19,
        "K" : 20
      }
    }, {
      "WK-27" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 4,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-28" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-29" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-30" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 6
      }
    }, {
      "WK-31" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 3,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-32" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 7,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-33" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-34" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-35" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-36" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-37" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-38" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-39" : {
        "I" : 42,
        "J" : 19,
        "K" : 20
      }
    }, {
      "WK-40" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 4,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-41" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-42" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-43" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 6
      }
    }, {
      "WK-44" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 3,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-45" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 7,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-46" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-47" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-48" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-49" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-50" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-51" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-52" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 4,
        "K" : 6
      }
    } ]
  },
  "Sheet1" : {
    "MONTH" : [ {
      "BL" : {
        "A" : 42,
        "B" : 19,
        "C" : 20,
        "D" : 11,
        "E" : 22,
        "F" : 44,
        "G" : 76,
        "H" : 12
      }
    }, {
      "JAN" : {
        "A" : 4,
        "B" : 4,
        "C" : 2,
        "D" : 1,
        "E" : 8,
        "F" : 7,
        "G" : 2,
        "H" : 5
      }
    }, {
      "FEB" : {
        "A" : 5,
        "B" : 6,
        "C" : 8,
        "D" : 9,
        "E" : 7,
        "F" : 6,
        "G" : 4,
        "H" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "MAR" : {
        "A" : 4,
        "B" : 2,
        "C" : 1,
        "D" : 9,
        "E" : 8,
        "F" : 7,
        "G" : 4,
        "H" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "APR" : {
        "A" : 5,
        "B" : 6,
        "C" : 6,
        "D" : 4,
        "E" : 3,
        "F" : 2,
        "G" : 1,
        "H" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "MAY" : {
        "A" : 5,
        "B" : 3,
        "C" : 2,
        "D" : 1,
        "E" : 6,
        "F" : 7,
        "G" : 6,
        "H" : 5
      }
    }, {
      "JUN" : {
        "A" : 6,
        "B" : 7,
        "C" : 8,
        "D" : 6,
        "E" : 4,
        "F" : 3,
        "G" : 2,
        "H" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "JUL" : {
        "A" : 4,
        "B" : 6,
        "C" : 3,
        "D" : 4,
        "E" : 5,
        "F" : 7,
        "G" : 9,
        "H" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "AUG" : {
        "A" : 1,
        "B" : 5,
        "C" : 3,
        "D" : 6,
        "E" : 7,
        "F" : 8,
        "G" : 1,
        "H" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "SEP" : {
        "A" : 4,
        "B" : 5,
        "C" : 4,
        "D" : 3,
        "E" : 5,
        "F" : 2,
        "G" : 4,
        "H" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "OCT" : {
        "A" : 1,
        "B" : 2,
        "C" : 4,
        "D" : 5,
        "E" : 7,
        "F" : 9,
        "G" : 8,
        "H" : 7
      }
    }, {
      "NOV" : {
        "A" : 5,
        "B" : 6,
        "C" : 8,
        "D" : 9,
        "E" : 7,
        "F" : 6,
        "G" : 4,
        "H" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "DEC" : {
        "A" : 4,
        "B" : 2,
        "C" : 1,
        "D" : 9,
        "E" : 8,
        "F" : 7,
        "G" : 4,
        "H" : 3
      }
    } ],
    "DAILY" : null,
    "WEEK" : [ {
      "BL" : {
        "I" : 42,
        "J" : 19,
        "K" : 20
      }
    }, {
      "WK-01" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 4,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-02" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-03" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-04" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 6
      }
    }, {
      "WK-05" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 3,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-06" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 7,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-07" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-08" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-09" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-10" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-11" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-12" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-13" : {
        "I" : 42,
        "J" : 19,
        "K" : 20
      }
    }, {
      "WK-14" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 4,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-15" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-16" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-17" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 6
      }
    }, {
      "WK-18" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 3,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-19" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 7,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-20" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-21" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-22" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-23" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-24" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-25" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-26" : {
        "I" : 42,
        "J" : 19,
        "K" : 20
      }
    }, {
      "WK-27" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 4,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-28" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-29" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-30" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 6
      }
    }, {
      "WK-31" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 3,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-32" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 7,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-33" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-34" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-35" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-36" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-37" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-38" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-39" : {
        "I" : 42,
        "J" : 19,
        "K" : 20
      }
    }, {
      "WK-40" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 4,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-41" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-42" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-43" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 6
      }
    }, {
      "WK-44" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 3,
        "K" : 2
      }
    }, {
      "WK-45" : {
        "I" : 6,
        "J" : 7,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-46" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-47" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 3
      }
    }, {
      "WK-48" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 5,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-49" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 4
      }
    }, {
      "WK-50" : {
        "I" : 5,
        "J" : 6,
        "K" : 8
      }
    }, {
      "WK-51" : {
        "I" : 4,
        "J" : 2,
        "K" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "WK-52" : {
        "I" : 1,
        "J" : 4,
        "K" : 6
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

**Suggested improvements**

You required all the structure to be Maps and Lists, however I think it would be lot nicer to have POJOs for `Workbook`, `Sheet`, `Table`. It would simplify the notation a great deal and could be written into JSON the same way using the `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and can you please help to do the same with multiple sheets which will have the same format.And the code to handle the dynamic change that is addition of headers(i.e Months , weeks ) in future we might also have something for daily and hourly.

Comment: @rahuluday Welcome! I can have a quick try at it, please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: @rahuluday Here you go, modified the code to handle several pages, and made it easy to add more tables if you need. Please upvote and accept the answer! Cheers!

Comment: Yeah will surely do that,sorry for troubling you again the code must be in such a way that it must dynamically take the headers from a config file that is months , weeks etc and the code must be able to read new header like for example daily ,hourly from config file.

Comment: private int MONTH_TABLE_HEADER_ROW = 0;
  private int MONTH_TABLE_VALUES_HEADER_COLUMN = 1;
  private int MONTH_TABLE_NB_VALUES_ROWS = 8;
  private int MONTH_TABLE_NB_VALUES_COLUMNS = 13;..... can you try to avoid the cell range and code in such a way that if a empty cell is encountered or if the next header is found and that must be the range instead. Can you please help me with it? @Bentaye

Comment: Right I will get the code to look for the table, given its name, and read until an empty column is found. But that will be the last modification :) I assume you know how to read a properties file, so I'll leave that out.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fd86Gk2mCW0zqBQVPetxfMuGfulxMLQR And this excel is modified please check out the sheet 2 @Bentaye

Comment: And this would make it easier like reading the excel file in CLI (args[]) .REQUESTING YOU

Comment: If you want to pass the filename as an argument, then use `args[0]` instead of the filename. This is it for me, I think I did a lot already.

Comment: THANK YOU  helped a lot @Bentaye

Comment: private Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>>parseSheet(XSSFSheet xsshSheet) {List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> months = extractTable(xsshSheet, "Month");
List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> weeks = extractTable(xsshSheet, "Week");
List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> days = extractTable(xsshSheet, "Daily");
Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>> sheet = new HashMap<>();
sheet.put("MONTH", months);..
return sheet;
}can you help in such a way that this can be read from property file and if change made in property file the code must not be changed

Comment: This is not hard, you can do it yourself, simply read your property file for the names of the tables you want, then just make a for loop in the `parseSheet` method to parse the tables you want: for(String tableName : tableNames) {
List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> table = extractTable(xsshSheet, tableName); sheet.put(tableName.toUppercase(), table); }

Comment: @Bentayae Thank you i tried out the above loop and it worked and I'm now facing another issue.The problem is im not able to get proper json data if i have more that 8 sheets.Can you please look in to it and help me resolving

Comment: In what way? is the 8th sheet different?

Comment: Even if the format is same it is not taking more than 8 sheet.And if it exceeds more that 8 sheet the json obtained is incomplete

Comment: No time right now but if you send me a link to the xls file I can try it out tomorrow

Comment: I guess the output is in string (i,e jsonstring) which will be able to hold around 2bytes data and the json data is exceeding 2bytes if it is more than 8 sheet.Please look into it @bentaye

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18LHpP4i4Rg5tnDNGx8l5R0dc-sVT2ntc This is the link for excel :) @bentaye

Comment: @rahuluday I just tried, it works fine, all sheets are in the JSON.
I suggest you create a new question for this problem if you can't sort it out.

Comment: In extractTable method can you help me changing the while(true) loops to for or for each loop? @Bentaye

Comment: Why?  A while loop is more appropriate. It can handle any table. If you want a for you will need to know in advance the number of rows and cold of the table you are extracting

Comment: In the program the loop will break if a null  or " "  ,this works fine the problem is while is a infite loop here and if the above condition fails then it will be a infinite loop so please help me out

Comment: Row valueHeaderRow = sheet.getRow(row);
Cell valueHeaderCell = valueHeaderRow.getCell(valuesHeaderColumn);
String valueHeader = valueHeaderCell.getStringCellValue();

for(int i=row; valueHeaderRow != null || !"".equals(valueHeader); i++){
    valueHeaderRow = sheet.getRow(row);
    valueHeaderCell = valueHeaderRow.getCell(valuesHeaderColumn);
    valueHeader = valueHeaderCell.getStringCellValue();


    Cell valueCell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col);
    Number value = valueCell.getNumericCellValue();
    values.put(valueHeader, value);
    row++;
} Tried something like this.